# CPU limit issue while testing APex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, before-trigger

I am quite lost on how I can migrate my Trigger to prod

the goal of my trigger is to assign specific contact to generic account when created
and the logic is, if a Generic account has less than 10000 contact assigned to it then assign the newly created contact to this account else create a new one and assign the contact to it

In my test I need to simulate the creation of more than 10k Contacts. if the I do not do it the part of the code where a new account is created is not run and I get only 60% coverage, not enough to migrate my trigger.
If I add it .. I then get a CPU error while trying to create 10k contacts in my test

In my test I tried to slit it like the following:

```
List<Contact> ContacttoCreate2 = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer i = 1000, j = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            string ContoCreate = 'Con' + String.valueOf(i);
            Contact x = new Contact();
            x.LastName = ContoCreate;
            x.RecordTypeId = '0128d000000p175AAA';
            x.Email = ContoCreate + '@selina.com';
            ContacttoCreate2.add(x); 
        }  
        insert(ContacttoCreate2);
        
        List<Contact> ContacttoCreate3 = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer i = 3000, j = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
            string ContoCreate = 'Con' + String.valueOf(i);
            Contact x = new Contact();
            x.LastName = ContoCreate;
            x.RecordTypeId = '0128d000000p175AAA';
            x.Email = ContoCreate + '@selina.com';
            ContacttoCreate3.add(x); 
        }  
        insert(ContacttoCreate3);
        
        List<Contact> ContacttoCreate4 = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer i = 4000, j = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            string ContoCreate = 'Con' + String.valueOf(i);
            Contact x = new Contact();
            x.LastName = ContoCreate;
            x.RecordTypeId = '0128d000000p175AAA';
            x.Email = ContoCreate + '@selina.com';
            ContacttoCreate4.add(x); 
        }  
        insert(ContacttoCreate4);
```

But did not help
My trigger look the following:

```
Public class ContactTriggerHandler{
    public static void afterInsert(List<Contact> newContactList){      
        AccountBuckets(newContactList);  
    }
    
    public static void AccountBuckets(List<Contact> newList){
        Id ContactRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('B2C_Guest').getRecordTypeId();
        if(newList[0].RecordTypeId == ContactRecordTypeId){
            Account[] AccToTake = [SELECT Name FROM Account where Name like 'B2CGeneric%'];
            string LastAccountCreated = 'B2CGeneric - ' + AccToTake.size();
            id currentAccId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account where Name = :LastAccountCreated].Id;
            //Finding the current number of Contact in the last account
            Integer AccountSize = [SELECT id from Contact Where account.Name = :LastAccountCreated].size();
            for(Contact ConItem :newList){
                if(AccountSize < 10000){
                    ConItem.AccountId = currentAccId;
                } else{
                    String NewName = 'B2CGeneric - ' + String.ValueOf(AccToTake.size()+1);
                    Account NewAccount = new Account();
                    NewAccount.name = NewName;
                    //Sandbox ID: 0128d000000p31BAAQ
                    //Prod ID:0128d000000p31BAAQ
                    NewAccount.RecordTypeId = '0128d000000p31BAAQ';
                    insert NewAccount;
            
                    Account Accd = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account where Name = :NewName];
                    system.debug(Accd);
                    id NewAccId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account where Name = :NewName].Id;
                    system.debug(NewAccId);
                    ConItem.AccountId = NewAccId;
                }         
            }           
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Your trigger contains a number of problems unrelated to the attempt to test at LDV. You should never hard-code Record Types (and in fact you have an example of the correct approach using `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()` already). Your logic assumes that all Contacts in the trigger set have the same Record Type, which is not guaranteed. And the trigger in general is not particularly well bulkified. The bulk patterns you're using are not as dangerous as some, but you're wasting SOQL and DML limits consistently.

Comment: Plus, you never perform DML on the `Contact` records, so it actually doesn't do anything and will throw a `FinalException`. Recommend using `before insert` rather than `after`.

Comment: Could you explain more that part: The bulk patterns you're using are not as dangerous as some, but you're wasting SOQL and DML limits consistently.
Everything else in your comment 100% agree

Comment: @Ben2pop You have both DML and SOQL queres inside of a loop. That's very bad practice, and the query for `NewAccId` is entirely unecessary (the query for `Accd` is also providing no benefit to you. You're setting the account name, and the Id is auto-populated after insert). Fixing those issues is a matter for another question.

Comment: You load up to 10,000 records worth of data (counting against the 50k row limit for SOQL) to load 1 record worth of data. You could instead use 1 row of SOQL limit with: `Integer accountSize = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :lastAccountId];` You also load every account created to support this model instead of just `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1`, then grabbing the number from the Account name.

Comment: Also remember that triggers run in batches of 200, so to insert 10k records in a single transaction means you'd run into SOQL ROW limit exceptions as written. Bulkification and such would help. For the actual unit test, if you want to get around the 10k limit, you can use `@TestSetup` to set up the first 9,999 contacts (the DML row limit is 10k), then you can use the unit test to create another 10,001 records.

Answer (score 6):

Inserting throngs upon throngs of records for tests is pretty much never the answer. Even if you didn't run into CPU limits, tests are still subject to the other governor limits as well (including the 10k DML row limit).

Now, there is a way to work around that to a degree, but there is a much, much easier approach here.

Instead of hard-coding the `10000` number, you should turn it into a class variable (static or instance, either would work). By having that variable available (either by making it `public`, using a constructor or method to inject a value, or using `@testVisible`), you can set it to a much more reasonable number, like 2, in your test methods.

The thing to realize here is that your goal is to test the action (assigning Contacts based on a threshold), not dictate the implementation (threshold = 10k).

Comment: Also note that allowing so many child records to be related to a single parent is a recipe for _index skew_, which can negatively impact query performance and may result in selectivity issues (which aren't particularly fun or easy to debug).

Comment: 10k is the recommended limit, but I agree, less is more.

Comment: Thx you, I am not sure how to implement what you described I set up in my trigger something such as @TestVisible private static Integer record threshold = 6000; How do I change it in my test class. ?

Comment: @Ben2pop You would want to keep this _outside_ of your trigger itself (because variables in triggers, static or otherwise, are usless outside of that trigger), but define it as a variable in your handler class. You'd then set it in your test exactly as you would with any other static or instance variable (e.g. `MyClass.myStaticVar = 'value';` or `MyClass instance = new MyClass(); instance.myVar = 'value';`)